# What's wrong with my netplan?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, netplan

I'm running opnsense in virtualbox on my ubuntu host and although it's working well, it has cut my network throughput by 75%, so I'd like to try and move to KVM on the host.

With virtualbox it was simple, set up two bridged network adapters for each host nic and away we go!

With KVM, its my understanding I need to bridge both adapters, via netplan in my case, in order to pass them as bridges to KVM. Well I thought I did that, but when I fire up OPNsense in KVM, it will NOT get a WAN IP no matter what I try...what am I missing?!

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp25s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
    enp25s0f1:
      dhcp4: true #this is true to get a LAN IP from OPNsense LAN DHCP
  bridges:
    wan1:
      interfaces: [enp25s0f0]
      dhcp4: true
    lan1:
      interfaces: [enp25s0f1]
      dhcp4: false
```

[1st bridged adapter WAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3qu7.png)

[2nd bridged adapter LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quzXW.png)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** What version of the Ubuntu OS are you running (please edit the question directly)? This may be useful in troubleshooting your issue. Thanks